# ROWNUM as a pseudo column equivalent in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

When using ROWNUM as a pseudo column how would you write the following query using T-SQL? Here is the full query. I realize it's written in PL/SQL and I will need to change addition objects.

```
BASE AS (
SELECT NULL AS ES_CMPNY_STATUS_KEY
  ,CSG.CMPNY_STATUS_GROUP
  ,CSG.CMPNY_STATUS_GROUP_ID
  ,CSG.CMPNY_STATUS_REASON
  ,CSG.CMPNY_STATUS_REASON_ID
  ,CSF.CMPNY_CURRENT_STATUS_FLAG
  ,TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS LOAD_DATE
  FROM CMPNY_STATUS_GROUP CSG
  CROSS JOIN CMPNY_CURRENT_STATUS_FLAG CSF
  ORDER BY CSG.CMPNY_STATUS_GROUP, CSG.CMPNY_STATUS_REASON

   )SELECT ROWNUM AS ES_CMPNY_STATUS_KEY
   ,CMPNY_STATUS_GROUP
   ,CMPNY_STATUS_GROUP_ID
   ,CMPNY_STATUS_REASON
   ,CMPNY_STATUS_REASON_ID
   ,CMPNY_CURRENT_STATUS_FLAG
   ,LOAD_DATE
 FROM BASE B
UNION
SELECT 0 AS ES_CMPNY_STATUS_KEY
  ,NULL AS CMPNY_STATUS_GROUP
  ,0 AS CMPNY_STATUS_GROUP_ID
  ,NULL AS CMPNY_STATUS_REASON
  ,0 AS CMPNY_STATUS_REASON_ID
  ,0 AS CMPNY_CURRENT_STATUS_FLAG
  ,TRUNC(SYSDATE) AS LOAD_DATE
  FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Is this MS T-SQL or Oracle PL-SQL?

Comment: It's PL/SQL that's being converted to T-SQL syntax.

Comment: So you are currently using an Oracle database, but you are converting to MS SQL Server?

Comment: Regardless, it seems that, based on your response to Gordon's answer, there is more to your original query that isn't included. Adding a window function shouldn't give you that error.

Comment: I added more context.

Comment: There's your problem. Remove `ORDER BY CSG.CMPNY_STATUS_GROUP, CSG.CMPNY_STATUS_REASON` from your CTE.

Comment: You'll want `WITH Base AS (...` and I'd recommend `UNION ALL` instead of just `UNION`. And do you need the CTE? I think you can just make the query without that CTE.

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks, Shawn! Working perfectly now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as ES_CMPNY_STATUS_KEY
```

Note that the `order by` is needed.  The `(select null)` appears -- in practice -- to avoid any additional sorting.  In general, though, you would include a column that specifies a sort order for the data you want.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Now I'm getting error: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 142
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: It is referencing a CTE.

Comment: Edit your question to include your full query.

Comment: @PJ.SQL . . . That is a different problem.  I would suggest that you ask another question.

Comment: @PJ.SQL I face the same error as "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified. " after using the provided solution, how you solve it finally?